# How to get all unique models of relations in collection items

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Let's say I have two related models `Student` and `Teacher`, where Student belongs to Teacher.

Now I have index method in controller where I'm returning all students with pagination and filters.

```
return new StudentCollection(
   Student::with('teacher')->where('age', 25)->paginate()
);
```

My student collection:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'data' => $this->collection,
        'teachers' => [], // here
    ];
}
```

Now I want to get all related teachers for those students. Problem I cannot use pluck on collection, because this query is paginated, but I need teachers for all found student's from my filters, not from one page.

How to achieve that?

Comment: To understand clearly, you want to load all eager loaded teacher in student collection ?

Comment: @Ali Yes, but not just from one returned by eloquent (mysql query) because it's paginated, but from all students within my filters (where) - in my example it's for students in age of 25. So let's say I have 10000 students and 100 teachers. In theory `teachers` field in collection can have more items, like 25 students in `data` (if pagination is set to 25), and 50 teachers in `teachers` field (because the rest of teachers do not match my students in age 25).

Comment: you need another query then ...